# jqvmap - no color in Gambia

Tags: jqvmap

I have installed jqvmap 1.0 in a site. Everything works fine but the color of Gambia. It appears transparent.

This is the path of Gambia. jqvmap 1.0:

```
"gm":{"path":"M406.89,298.34l-0.13,1.11l6.92-0.1l0.35-1.03l-0.15-1.04l-1.99,0.81L406.89,298.34L406.89,298.34z","name":"Gambia"}
```

I did compare this path with the original. There are no differences between them.

I did download version 1.1 and placed its jquery.vmap.world.js (paths definition). The problem wasn't fixed.

I did set this color for Gambia an other countries.

```
"gm":"199.18" (light orange)
```

Gambia is the only country that is not showing its color. As you can see, even some tiny islands, smaller than Gambia, are showing correctly the color. Any idea?

[image: Transparent Gambia]

Comment: can you see if that path alone defines a shape and give it a colour. Maybe a fiddle for us to playaround and test this.

Comment: I did eliminate all the paths except by Gambia. I did also increase the size of the DIV in order to see if the path of Gambia defines a shape and shows the color. There is all the info. The problem is the path of Gambia is too narrow, so the borders cover the shape. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please put your answer as an answer and mark it as solution and as community wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some tests I did realize that the problem was caused by a couple of issues:

- The path is too narrow so the border was covering the shape (hidding its color).
- Visually, the color of the shape plus the color and opacity (0.8) of the border did result in a color very similar to the background color.

So, the perception of a "non colored" shape was caused by an optical illusion.

To fix that I did change lines 51 an 52 of jquery.vmap.js from:

```
  51    borderWidth: 1,
  52    borderOpacity: 0.8,
```

to

```
  51    borderWidth: 0.3,
  52    borderOpacity: 0.5,
```

Thanks for the helps.